# Assassin's Creed IV - Black Flag - is there any counter of our death in statistics?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Can we check in Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag game how many times we suffered death in some statistics or something like that? Or no?

Answer (score 1):

No sadly there is not the option to see the number of deaths.